# Oracle search text with non-english characters

Tags: oracle, encoding, utf-8, internationalization

Our Oracle DB is UTF8. We are storing addresses that need to be searchable. Some of the street names contain non-english characters (e.g. Peña Báináõ ) this needs to be searchable either as "**Peña Báináõ**" or with english equivalent charactes like "**Pena Bainao**". What we did is to convert the text on the query, something like:

```
SELECT CONVERT('Peña Báináõ','US7ASCII') as converted FROM dual;
```

But the issue here is that not all of the characters have an English equivalent (not even some pretty obvious ones like ñ or õ) so we end up with the text converted to:

```
Pe?a Baina?
```

So if the user tries to find that addres typing "**Pena Bainao**" he can't find it because "**Pena Bainao**" is different from ""**Pe?a Baina?**"".

We have figured out some dirty workarrounds on this, but I wanted to check first if someone has found a more elegant solution.

Here is a list of some characters that are not converted to US7ASCII:

```
Character     UTF8 Code     Possible Equivalent   
æ         -   u00E6      -      ae
å         -   u00E5      -       a
ã         -   u00E3      -       a
ñ         -   u00F1      -       n
õ         -   u00F5      -       o
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Using `nlssort` with BINARY_AI (Both case and accent insentive):

```
SQL> select nlssort('Peña Báináõ', 'NLS_SORT = BINARY_AI') C from dual;

C
------------------------
70656E61206261696E616F00

SQL> select nlssort('Pena Bainao', 'NLS_SORT = BINARY_AI') C from dual;

C
------------------------
70656E61206261696E616F00

SQL> select nlssort('pena bainao', 'NLS_SORT = BINARY_AI') C from dual;

C
------------------------
70656E61206261696E616F00

SQL> select 'true' T from dual where nlssort('pena bainao', 'NLS_SORT = BINARY_AI') = nlssort('Peña Báináõ', 'NLS_SORT = BINARY_AI') ;

T
----
true
```

2) You could also alter the NLS_SORT session variable to binary_ai and then you would not have to specify NLS_SORT every time:

```
SQL> select 'true' T from dual where nlssort('pena bainao') = nlssort('Peña Báináõ') ;

no rows selected

SQL> alter session set nls_sort = binary_ai;

Session altered.

SQL> select 'true' T from dual where nlssort('pena bainao') = nlssort('Peña Báináõ') ;

T
----
true
```

3) To drop the use of `nlssort` function and change the sematics of everything, also set the nls_comp session variable:

```
SQL> select 'true' T from dual where 'pena bainao' = 'Peña Báináõ';

no rows selected

SQL> alter session set nls_comp = linguistic;

Session altered.

SQL> select 'true' T from dual where 'pena bainao' = 'Peña Báináõ';

T
----
true
```

Option 1 changes only local behavior, the query where you want different results. Option 2 and 3 will change behavior of other queries and may not be what you want. See [Table 5-2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm#CIHBFIID) of [Oracle® Database Globalization Support Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/toc.htm). Also look the section "[Using Linguistic Indexes](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm#i1006421)" to see how to be able to use indexes.

Comment: also consider SOUNDEX and other similarity based functions.

Comment: `soundex('Pena Bainao')` yeilds P515, `soundex('Peña Báináõ')` yeilds P150. Session parameters NLS_SORT and NLS_COMP doe not affect the results.

Comment: @Shannon Severance: Great, ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC and ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI not also did the trick but they reduced the complexity of the query significantly. Thanks a lot!