# equalignorecase in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

From the following question,

[SQL server ignore case in a where expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224364/sql-server-ignore-case-in-a-where-expression)

Is it possible with Oracle?

Also, is it possible to compare "your,text" with "your text"?

I want to convert All characters other than A-Z0-9 into space and then compare the string.

I can do it by Java methods through regex but don't prefer writing unecessary code.

Comment: For another way, see examples of NLS_SORT and NLS_COMP at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682173/oracle-search-text-with-non-english-characters/6684663#6684663

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with the `UPPER()` function.

```
select whatever from your_table where UPPER(col) = UPPER('YourText');
```

(Or `LOWER()` if you prefer that.)

Performance warning: that won't play well with indexes, unless you've indexed on `UPPER(col)` also and are careful with `NULL`s.